# How long should the sweep be over the framed shower door bottom edge?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower, seal

My bathroom has a framed shower door. Give the measurements shown, how deep (long) the sweep should be over the door bottom edge? I tried 1”, but the sweep is always clamped by the door and metal under it.

Please ignore the duct tape, which is just a temporary measure, and drip rail and the attached sweep will be installed eventually.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: which way does the door swing, inside or outside the tub?

Comment: @FreeMan outside

Answer (score 1):

#### The "sweep" needs to be shorter than the gap so it doesn't sit outside the bracket.

Any drop that will pass over the bracket should be fine if it is on the inside edge.  All you need is for water to not get over the top of the bracket.  You might get away with the rubber being a bit longer than the gap, but it seems like that would get messed up when it is at the angle in your photo.  As long as you aren't powering water at the gap you should be fine.

Comment: Thus 1/4" overhang is enough?

Comment: It should be, @bobby_yan. The door opens out, so the sweep needs to be short enough to not get caught on the metal flange when it closes. When the door is closed, 1/4" should be more than enough to kick the water off the door inward, away from the edge of the tub. Splashes would have to go _up_, under the 1/4" sweep at _exactly_ the right angle to go directly over the 3/4" angle on the outside in order to escape - not impossible, but not likely. The 1/2-dozen that escape each week or so should be easy to dry up with your bathmat or the edge of the towel hitting the ground when you dry yourself

Comment: Since you've already got duck-tape there, cut it down to 1/4" to test this out. Shower for a week or two and see how little water actually escapes. If you feel it's too much, put a new one on at 3/8" and see if that satisfies you. Once you're happy, put an "official" sweep of the desired length in place of the duck-tape tester.